# Вычисление даты рождения

Tags: javascript

Есть 2 поля. 1 - поле числового ввода (поле ввода возраста), 2 - DatePicker (в нем можно выбрать дату dd/mm/yyyy). Нужна такая функция, которая при вводе числа в поле возраста, подставляла значения в DatePicker. ПРИМЕР: написал 10 , а в поле появилось значение 01/01/2008.
Как реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.age').on('change',function(e){
  var year=parseInt(2019)-parseInt($(this).val(),10);
  $('.date').text('01/01/'+year);
});
```